# Validate a Single line of text column type of list in sharepoint 2010 to accept only alphabets?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, calculated-columns

How to validate a Single line of text column type of list in sharepoint 2010 to enter accept only alphabets? no special character and no number should be allowed in that field.

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the best ways to apply client-side validation in SharePoint **2010** would be to  override `PreSaveAction` handler.

> `PreSaveAction` function is a user defined function that allows to
>   override standard behavior for a Save button handler in List Forms on the client-side.

Regarding validation expression, we could use `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` regular expression to accept only letters

---

Let's say we need to validate `Notes` field in `Links` list to accept only letters, then the following steps demonstrate how to apply those changes:

Steps:

1. Open New Form page in Edit mode
2. Add Content Editor web part on the page
3. Insert the code provided below into `Content` property of Content Editor web
   part

Code:

```
<script>
function isLetter(val) { 
    var re = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    return re.test(val);
} 


function PreSaveAction(){

    var commentsBox = findFieldControl('Notes');  //find field control by title
    if (!isLetter(commentsBox.val())) {
        var errorHtml = '<br/><span class="ms-formvalidation"><span role="alert">Only letters are allowed<br></span></span>';
        commentsBox.after(errorHtml);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function findFieldControl(fieldTitle)
{
    var control = $('[title="' + fieldTitle + '"]');
    return control;
}

</script>​​​​​​
```

### Results

[image]

Some additional information about client-side validation in SharePoint 2010/2013 could be found in [this post](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/03/14/introduction-to-client-forms-validation-in-sharepoint-2013/).